# Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'Interval'

Tags: python

I'm using this package 'from xverse.ensemble import VotingSelector' for my code.

When I was trying to run the VotingSelector() an error message just popped up on my output screen, warning the impossibility of comparison.

It's quite weird 'cause I've met all the requirements for using the package, specially Encoder code to treat categorical features and '.fillna' to replace NaN with zero.

Here is my code and what I've done:

```
# Encoder
cat_encoder = ce.CatBoostEncoder(handle_missing='value', handle_unknown='value')

# .fit_tranform for Training dataset
X_train_selection = cat_encoder.fit_transform(X_train.drop(['id','date_reference'],axis=1).copy(),y_train.copy())

# .fit_tranform for Testing dataset
X_test_selection = cat_encoder.transform(X_test.drop(['id', 'date_reference'], axis=1).copy())

# a sample to run faster the code
sample_index = X_train_selection.sample(10000, random_state=1).index

# .fit
clf = VotingSelector()
X = X_train_selection.loc[sample_index].fillna(0)
y = y_train.loc[sample_index].fillna(0)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

while printing it showed:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'Interval'
```